# urxvt real transparency not working in i3wm

Tags: transparency, archlinux, i3, urxvt

I am running Arch Linux with i3wm. I have customized i3 a lot already, but I also wanted to try transparency in urxvt. The pseudo-transparency does work, but when I try real transparency, instead of making the terminal transparent, it just becomes darker.

In my .Xdefaults file I have:

```
urxvt.depth: 32
urxvt.background: [75]#0e192e
urxvt.cursorcolor: #ffffff
urxvt.foreground: #ffffff
```

I have removed all the pseudo transparency stuff like `urxvt.transparency` and `urxvt.shading`.

In my ~/.config/i3/config file I use `exec_always --no-startup-id feh --randomize --bg-fill ~/wallpapers/*` to set the wallpaper.

I think it's likely that it has something to do with the wallpaper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

one solution would be to use Compton compositor - https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/compton